# Rails 5 Permitting controller action changed params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

So i have the following params permitted.

```
p = params.permit(:a, :b, :c, :lines => [:location_id, :quantity, :product => [:id]])
```

In my controller action, i add to the `lines` param the data i've permitted.

```
p['lines'] << {"product"=>{"id"=>"123456"}, "quantity"=>"2", "location_id"=>"123456"}
```

This is how the params looked after they've been changed.

```
puts params['lines']
#> [<ActionController::Parameters {"product"=>{"id"=>"123456"}, "quantity"=>"2", "location_id"=>"123456"} permitted: false>]
```

But as you can see it's not permitted. What am i missing here? I am using Rails 5.

Comment: Can you please post your code as it is called - on just line by line. Because at the moment I understand that you add values to the hash after you called permit. And that wouldn't work. Furthermore, why do you need to add something to the params. What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

To get permitted (whitelisted) params, you always have to make sure that you call the permitted version, `p` in your case, whenever `params` changes.

The difference between `params` and `p` is that `params.permit(...)` returns a permitted copy of itself and assigns it to `p`. So `params` permission state remains unchanged.

Try with `puts p['lines']` instead of `puts params['lines']` to see if you get the desired result.